# Sklearn: Get probabilities from multi class classification that are independent of each other

Tags: python, scikit-learn, random-forest, prediction

I have a multi class classification problem where I want to get the predictions as probabilities that are independent of each other. For example there are 4 classes being predicted, currently the output for first observation looks like:

```
[0.27661473, 0.34121073, 0.25299197, 0.12918257]
```

Where the probabilities sum to 1.

Is it possible to get it so they don't depend on each other, i.e. treat each one as a binary without having to make 4 separate binary classifiers?

Comment: Out of interest, and to assist in answering, why would do you want to do this?

Comment: I'm doing propensity modelling so need outputs to be probabilities but independent of each other because a person may have a high propensity for 2 classes (one very high, one less high).

Comment: Most scikit-learn estimators do exactly this. They break up multi-class into binary by using OneVsRest approach. And then combine the probabilities as a last step. So if you show the code, or tell which estimator you are using, maybe we can work something out. Anyways, in all cases, you can use [OneVsRestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.multiclass.OneVsRestClassifier.html) to get binary classifiers.

Comment: @VivekKumar - It looks like Random Forests from the tag. If so, Random Forests are one of the scikit-learn models that do predict across all classes, then use this to get a pred_proba score.

Comment: @josh Aah yes, I did not see that. Yes, RandomForestClassifier (and other tree based classifiers and others [as mentioned here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/multiclass.html)) are inherently multi-class. They use the inherent relationships between classes to train. So we have no way to de-couple them, other than to explicitly change the problem to multiple binary problems and then get the probabilities.

Comment: To the OP, if you are using RandomForestClassifier, then you cannot get independent probabilities of each class. You [can start here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiclass_classification#Transformation_to_binary), and then as I suggested in my previous comment, use OneVsRestClassifier.

Comment: @VivekKumar, just confirming, it's not possible to do this with random forest and my only solution is to use 4 separate binary classifiers?

Comment: Yes, see the [`predict_proba()` description here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html#sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.predict_proba):- `"The predicted class probabilities of an input sample are computed as the mean predicted class probabilities of the trees in the forest. The class probability of a single tree is the fraction of samples of the same class in a leaf."`